# Error adding feature to centroids in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, centroids

I want to map forest stands. I have the compartments as centroids and I am trying to add a feature by snapping to them and creating polygons. Each time I click, however, it displays a box titled "Compart...", with an text box after the letters DN. It doesn't matter what I enter, I can't seem to create a polygon.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're doing. If you snap to centroids you won't be recreating polygons around them, you'll be using them for new polygon vertices. Exactly what tools/steps are you using? If you're trying to outline the stands, centroids won't do you much good except to roughly identify where they are (if some are adjacent you'll know it's not just one big one) or creating Voronoi/Thiessen polygons (which probably won't work if there are gaps between stands).